# Increment xcode project User-Defined Variable through Script

Tags: ios, xcode, bash, shell, run-script

I want to increment the User-Defined variable in xcode project. Is there any script to increment User-Defined variables.

I have a user-defined variable **"PATCH"**. And in info.plist, I am assigning this Variable to Bundle version.

I want that this User-Defined Variable will auto-increment when I archive the project using different configurations.

I am attaching the screenshots, hope it will help you to understand my question easily:

Xcode Screenshot:

[image: Build Setting- Xcode]

Plist screenshot:

[image]

I also go through these Links:

[Xcode AutoIncrement Build Version.](https://gist.github.com/sekati/3172554)

[StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286937/how-to-auto-increment-bundle-version-in-xcode-4)

But these questions/links did not match my requirement. All I need is to access user-defines variable through script. please help if any one has solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A word of warning; once you figure out how to set the required values in the `info.plist` ensure you implement the script as a separate target using the *External Build System* template, and make your app target dependent upon this target.  You don't want to be messing with `info.plist` as part of the normal build process.  There be dragons!

Comment: I am building my project through jenkins CI and I have different jobs for different configurations. What I need is to increment my variable so that I donot increment build version manually. It will also be done automatically. What are the drawbacks in my above solution. Can u explain me a little bit?

Comment: You can still use the separate target approach from a command line build, but you might have issues detecting if you are archiving when using a separate target (I cannot remember to be honest).

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?  I'm after the same thing.  Thanks!

Comment: not yet!! :( I am manually increment the variables.

Comment: If this is actually a bash problem, and all you want is to increment a number in `info.plist` file, what does the file look like?

Comment: Here is the duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/38328837/5790492

Answer (score -1):

You need to update the file `project.pbxproj` in *.xcodeproj/.

For example, if you need to update the `Debug` build number of PATCH. First find the identifier in `project.pbxproj` for the `Debug` build, you should get something like 13B07F941A680F5B00A75B9A. Then you can do

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :objects:13B07F941A680F5B00A75B9A:buildSettings:PATCH" project.pbxproj
# which should give 90
```

Then you can update it with (make a backup copy of project.pbxproj first) :

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set :objects:13B07F941A680F5B00A75B9A:buildSettings:PATCH 91" project.pbxproj
```

Verify again with :

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :objects:13B07F941A680F5B00A75B9A:buildSettings:PATCH" project.pbxproj
# which should give 91
```

Also check in xcode.

Comment: Unfortunately PlistBuddy format .pbxproj to xml-format plist so source control getting stack and the information is lost. So I can't use this solution(

Comment: @NikKov  What do you mean by `getting stack` ?

Comment: It means that too many changes. Because the project.pbxproj is completely different after `PlistBuddy set`. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/69519219/5790492 to learn what to do.

Answer (score -2):

Thx @Philippe, i've made a bash script:

```
# - RELEASE EBF737881ECAECD400F5A5DF
# - DEBUG EBF737871ECAECD400F5A5DF

currentVersion=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :objects:EBF737871ECAECD400F5A5DF:buildSettings:FC_VERSION" ../FormaCar.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj)
newVersion="${currentVersion%.*}.$((${currentVersion##*.}+1))"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set :objects:EBF737871ECAECD400F5A5DF:buildSettings:FC_VERSION $newVersion" ../FormaCar.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set :objects:EBF737881ECAECD400F5A5DF:buildSettings:FC_VERSION $newVersion" ../FormaCar.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
echo "Old version: $currentVersion. Version bumped to: $newVersion"
```

where `FC_VERSION` is user-defined parameter and holds a version in `x.x.x` format.

and in `Fastfile`

```
lane :bumpMinorVersionNumber do
  sh "./bumpMinorVersionNumber.sh"
end
```

This script bumps the minor version of FC_VERSION setting and works via fastlane

**UPDATE:**

Unfortunately PlistBuddy [format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56179405/5790492) .pbxproj to xml-format plist so source control getting stack and the information is lost. So I can't use this solution(

Thx to https://stackoverflow.com/a/56179405/5790492 and https://nshipster.com/xcconfig/
I've created the **xcconfig** file, added it to project in Info tab. For fastlane added [this](https://github.com/sovcharenko/fastlane-plugin-xcconfig) plugin to work with xcconfig. And now lane looks like:

```
currentBuildNumber = get_xcconfig_value(path: 'fastlane/VersionsConfig.xcconfig',
                                        name: 'FC_BUILD')
newBuildNumber = currentBuildNumber.to_i + 1
update_xcconfig_value(path: 'fastlane/VersionsConfig.xcconfig',
                      name: 'FC_BUILD',
                      value: newBuildNumber.to_s)
UI.important("Old build number: #{currentBuildNumber}. Build number bumped to: #{newBuildNumber}")
```

#### It works like a charm!

Answer (score -5):

I would suggest you use something like [fastlane](http://fastlane.tools) to accomplish this (there is an action called `increment_build_number` which does specifically this, more info on the [actions page](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/docs/Actions.md)).
From code point of view, if you need to access that variable I use something like:
`NSString *buildVersion = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"BUILD_VERSION"];`

Also, I noticed that in the plist file you use `${PATCH}` ...I think that's supposed to have the same name as the user-defined variable in your project.