# What tools support editing project.pbxproj files?

Tags: ios, xcode, plist, xcode-project

I want to edit `project.pbxproj` straight up using command line (for CI server script)

what tools can allow me to do this?

I used to use `PlistBuddy` to edit the output `Info.plist`; however, what i really want to do is to edit this user defined field, which is used in multiple places, and i really don't want to have to hunt that down in every plist location

Comment: Hi. Can you explain for what you want to edit a `.pbxproj` file?

Comment: a User defined field

Comment: You can try a `*.xcconfig` files, plus a `user defined fields` may redefine from cmd line. This is a build step from `teamcity CI`: `xcodebuild -project 'MyApp.xcodeproj' -scheme 'MyAppStaticTeamcity' -configuration 'Debug' -sdk 'iphoneos' GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS='$GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 MY_LOG_LEVEL=2' clean build`

Comment: @Mozilla actually, i didn't realize you can pass in preprocessor flags. would this work directly if i just want to pass in one random field, say something like `"USER_DEFINED_VARIABLE=${hi}"` ??

Comment: Maybe you went the wrong way. If you have a frequently changing parameter, it is easier to carry out it in `* .plist` as a setting. Replacement a value in the `* .plist` much easier than editing the project file or pass the user defined field (see `plistbuddy`). In my project I have the setting `server_address` which placed in the `*.plist`.

Comment: Ah i see i see. that makes sense. thanks!! would you like to write your thoughts as an answer so that i can upvote and accet?

Comment: `project.pbxproj` is a `plist` file, too. So you can use `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` to edit it.

Comment: @SergeMaslyakov Yes, you are right.`xcconfig` is a much better way than `project.pbxproj` file. And `perl` is good at editing `xcconfig` file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`project.pbxproj` is an [old-style ASCII property list](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/OldStylePlists/OldStylePLists.html) file, too. So you can use `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy` to edit it.

Print some User-Defined key's value like this,

```bash
# Get the key A83311AA20DA4A80004B8C0E in your project.pbxproj
# LZD_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_BUNDLE_ID is defined by me,
# Replace key paths with your own.
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'print :objects:A83311AA20DA4A80004B8C0E:buildSettings:LZD_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_BUNDLE_ID' LAAppAdapter.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

Set its value like this,

```bash
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'set :objects:A83311AA20DA4A80004B8C0E:buildSettings:LZD_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE_BUNDLE_ID com.dawnsong.notification-service' LAAppAdapter.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
```

**UPDATE**
`PlistBuddy` will automatically convert `project.pbxproj` into a xml-format plist file since macOS Catalina (or some earlier version). It's better to move the setting item into **`xcconfig` file instead**  since `xcconfig` is much smaller and simpler than `project.pbxproj` and not easy to make mistakes when editing with **`perl` script**.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful. This is the right answer IMO.

Comment: printing values with `project.pbxproj ` seems to work fine, but when I use the `set` command the whole project.pbxproj gets converted to an XML .plist file and can no longer be read by Xcode.

Comment: You just made my day sir !

Comment: Same error for me, have you found a workaround @Mr.Zystem?

Comment: @sachadso I think `PlistBuddy`'s `-x` option becomes default. It's [strange](https://scriptingosx.com/2018/02/defaults-the-plist-killer/).

Comment: [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/SerializePlist/SerializePlist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH7-SW1) said, "Because you cannot save a property list in the old-style (OpenStep) format, the only valid format parameters for this method are NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 and NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0". I think it explains why and what happens

Comment: @sachadso found no solution, so I stopped trying to mess around with the .pbxproj file.

Answer (score 20):

I know this has been answered for a while, but since the original question is about tools supporting the manipulation of `.pbxproj` files, and many other people may be looking for the same information, here's how I do it. It took me quite a while to figure this out because I was very unfamiliar with Xcode when I started attempting this, so I hope this saves others the hours of grief I had to put in.

You can use the `plutil` command to transform the `.pbxproj` file from the legacy `.plist` format into an XML or JSON format you will be able to manipulate more easily. I'm using JSON. To do so, just run:

```
plutil -convert json project.pbxproj
```

This will convert the format of `project.pbxproj`, but be aware that -contrary to common sense- the output won't be another file with a JSON extention such as `project.json`. What will happen is that `project.pbxproj` will be converted to JSON format, but retain it's cryptic `.pbxproj` extension. So even though the file's format has been changed, Xcode will still pick it up and use it in its new JSON format.

Then you can change `project.pbxproj` with ease using any JSON manipulation tool of your choosing. I'm using Groovy's `JsonSlurper` class in a Groovy script.

**Note** I also explored the XML option, but I found the `project.pbxproj` file in XML format to be cumbersome to parse. The elements are not properly nested to allow for traversing the tree with ease. It's plagued with:

```
<key>someKey</key>
<dict>
    <!--More elements which provide configuration for the key above-->
</dict>
```

So it's positional in nature. You have to look for the `key` element corresponding to the setting you want to manipulate and then jump to the `dict` element just after it. Which means you have to mount the children of each XML element into an array, in order to index them.

Comment: Nice explanation. Thanks for sharing this. It saves lots of time for me and may saves time for many other.

Comment: No problem @TheiOSDev, would you mind voting up my answer then? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Convering the pbxproj file to JSON did not work for me.  Xcode 10 says the file is corrupted and won't open after it's converted.

Comment: @PaulSlocum have you tried upgrading the `plutil` command? It's possible that you're working with an old `plutil` version that's not capable of handling the `.pbxproj` format produced by Xcode 10+ I use Brew. I just tried `brew outdated` and got this `libplist (1.12) < 2.0.0_1`. I looked it up and found it [here](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/libplist). Sadly, there's no `-v` or `--version` option in `plutil` but `brew upgrade libplist` will either get you the latest version or say `Error: libplist 2.0.0_1 already installed`.

Comment: Wow I had no idea that Xcode could support this. Thanks!

Comment: xcode add file  convert project.pbxproj back to legacy format

Answer (score 10):

Here are 3 open-source tools which implement .pbxproj file editing:

- https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj (Ruby based)
- https://github.com/apache/cordova-node-xcode (NodeJS based)
- https://github.com/kronenthaler/mod-pbxproj (Python based)

Personally, I made the best experience with the NodeJS based tool. So far it has covered all our needs reliably.

In the following is listed an example javascript file `update-project.js` which sets the developer team ID, app entitlements, adds a `GoogleService-Info.plist` file to the project and checks it as part of the build target. Take it as an inspiration and adapt the scripts and its paths to your needs:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const xcode = require('xcode')

if (process.argv.length !== 3) {
  console.error("Please pass the development team ID as the first argument")
  process.exit(1)
}
const developmentTeamId = process.argv[2]
const path = 'ios/App/App.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj'
const project = xcode.project(path)

project.parse(error => {
  const targetKey = project.findTargetKey('App')
  const appGroupKey = project.findPBXGroupKey({path: 'App'})
  project.addBuildProperty('CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS', 'App/App.entitlements')
  project.addBuildProperty('DEVELOPMENT_TEAM', developmentTeamId)
  project.addFile('App.entitlements', appGroupKey)
  project.removeFile('GoogleService-Info.plist', appGroupKey)
  const f = project.addFile('GoogleService-Info.plist', appGroupKey, {target: targetKey})
  f.uuid = project.generateUuid()
  project.addToPbxBuildFileSection(f)
  project.addToPbxResourcesBuildPhase(f)
  fs.writeFileSync(path, project.writeSync())
})
```

Above script can be executed with

`yarn run update-project <arguments...>`

given that `update-project` is registered in `package.json`:

```
{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "update-project": "node update-project.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: thats amazing, thank you! the simplest way to workaround installing some SDKs including firebase and setting GoogleService-Info.plist in place.