# How to automatically set the version and build number of a Watchkit app target

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch

The version and build number (or version and short version) of a Watchkit app and extension have to be set to the same value as the containing app.

I use environment variables to set the apps version in the `Info.plist` dynamically at build time. That also works fine for the Watchkit extension, but not for the Watchkit app.

The environment variables I use have to be provided in the plist for the main app and extension without `${}` (for variable `${VERSION}` I set `VERSION`).
if I do the same for the Watchkit app, it is taking the string itself, not the value. If I provide it with dollar & brackets there is no data in the variable.

Any idea how to set the variables for the Watchkit app?

Comment: Similar Question: [How to auto-increment Bundle Version in Xcode 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6286937/642706)

Comment: “I use environment variables to set the apps version in the Info.plist dynamically at build time.” — I'm here to find out how you do that.

Comment: It's 2022 and this is now very simple - see my answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/72790925/7107094

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if it doesn´t work like this, do it with a `Run Script Build Phase`. Do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
INFOPLIST="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
echo "writing to $INFOPLIST"
PLISTCMD="Set :CFBundleVersion $(git rev-list --all|wc -l)"
echo -n "$INFOPLIST" | xargs -0 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "$PLISTCMD"
```

I don´t have the right paths for your WatchKit App, so you will have to change that yourself.

Comment: Already found that solution, but I prefer agvtool - it sets all plists in one go

Comment: Nice! Can you share the solution?

Comment: planned to do so - actually that's what you commented on yesterday, when I misunderstood some question ...

Comment: That won't work as you can't (as of Xcode 6.3) add any kind of build phases to a watchkit app, only the watchkit extension can have build phases.

Comment: That´s right, my answer was related to Xcode 6.2, where the WatchKit App didn´t neither had the Build Settings tab nor had the check for same CFBundleVersion.

Comment: See my answer for a working solution. It's working great with all versions including 6.3.1

Comment: Yeah, agvtool is good, but I don´t want to use a second target for the deployment process. And for the manual setting with PListBuddy, I´m struggling with the timing and which-file-is-read-or-written-before-what-else.

Comment: I´ve managed to get it working now, will update my answer in the next days.

Comment: Hi @stk, I use Svn to commit my version and not git, how can I use ur script for my extension? Thanks

Answer (score 23):

I use this to update all the targets:

```
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$SRCROOT/Great WatchKit App/Info.plist"
```

Comment: Is there a way to generalize the last line so it works in any app?

Comment: sure. see my answer below (or above if I get voted :))

Comment: In last line Instead of Great WatchKit App, should I write the name of my main app or the name of extension.

Answer (score 17):

My `CFBundleVersion` is the number of commits on my `master` branch on the git repo.

On my main app target, in `Build Phases` > `+ New Run Script Phase` I've added this script:

```
# Set the build number to the count of Git commits
buildNumber=$(git rev-list --count HEAD)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$SRCROOT/app WatchKit Extension/Info.plist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$SRCROOT/app WatchKit App/Info.plist"
```

From `app WatchKit App` the `app` should be the name of your app, but check the exact path.

Comment: At which position in your Build Phases did you add this? Before 'Compile Sources'?

Comment: After, it's the last one. I've marked `Run script only when installing` so it will increment only on archives. Didn't like to pollute every commit with a change on 3 plists.

Comment: I had to add this run script just after the **Copy Bundle Resources**, otherwise I got a failed build with complaining on non matching version numbers (however after the build the version numbers where all identical).

Comment: For my configuration, I needed to replace `"${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"` with `"${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"`.

Comment: If you change the build number for the plist files within `BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR`, then they won't be tracked by Git in your main project directory, as explained [here](http://blog.jaredsinclair.com/post/97193356620/the-best-of-all-possible-xcode-automated-build). For example: iOS App: `"${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"`, Watch app: `"${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/../${CONFIGURATION}-watchos/MyApp_Watch.app/Info.plist"` and Watch extension: `"${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/../${CONFIGURATION}-watchos/MyApp_Watch_Extension.appex/Info.plist"`.

Comment: Should I add this script to my extension or also to may main app? If I add only to my extension is it going to work? Since in my main app has many script...

Answer (score 10):

You can update the build version of all your targets without a build script. (You can also use this to update the marketing / short build version; in this case ignore changes to CFBundleVersion).

Open your project settings and set CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION (Current Project Version) to the desired version number. In all targets make sure CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION is empty (so that its value is inherited from the project). Then in all Info.plist files set CFBundleShortVersionString (Bundle versions string, short) and CFBundleVersion (Bundle version / build version) to $(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION).

Optionally, you can distinguish between the build version and the "marketing" version (this is useful if the build version is generated automatically). To do so, in your project settings, set MARKETING_VERSION (Marketing Version) to the desired version number. As before, make sure all targets inherit the value from the project. Finally, in all Info.plist files set CFBundleShortVersionString (Bundle versions string, short) to $(MARKETING_VERSION).

If you want to increment your CFBundleVersion on each build (or to have it reflect your git SHA). Use agvtool as described by dogsgod or see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1827/_index.html.

Comment: for me this is the correct answer, as all scripting is not needed and it seems this is what Apple thought it should be like.

Comment: For the CFBundleShortVersionString (Bundle versions string, short) I would use $(MARKETING_VERSION)

Comment: I agree this should be the accepted answer. Scripting shouldn't be necessary & creates more complexity than we need to deal with. Thanks for the simple solution.

Answer (score 6):

stk's answer is right, but I wanted to add my findings as well.

One way to solve the problem is by using `agvtools`:

Create a new target in *OSX > Other > External Build Sytem* 
Add a run script similar to this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

#read vesion number from version.txt in project root
VERSION=$(head -n 1 version.txt)
BUILD=`git rev-list $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) | wc -l | awk '{ print $1 }'`

echo "${VERSION} (${BUILD})"

agvtool new-marketing-version ${VERSION}
agvtool new-version -all ${BUILD}

exit 0
```

I have a `version.txt` file with only my version number in it (*marketing version* or *short bundle version*) that can be easily adjusted by any CI system and use the number of my git SHAs as build number (*bundle version*)
Adjust the sources for `VERSION` and `BUILD` to fit your requirements

Run the scheme that has been created for the new target before your build/archiving.

In case you need to have this as a dependency for your main target - this will fail, as it will stop the execution of the following targets (if somebody knows how to prevent that, I would be thankful for a hint)

But you can still achieve that with a script like the following executed for each of your plists (similar to what stk provided):

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# usage:
# set-version-in-plist.sh LIST VERSION BUILD
# LIST:      Info.plist path & name
# VERSION:   version number xxx.xxx.xxx
# BUILD:     build number xxxxx
#

# Location of PlistBuddy
PLISTBUDDY="/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy"

${PLISTBUDDY} -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $2" "$1";
${PLISTBUDDY} -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $3" "$1";
```

Save this script as a file, make it executable (`chmod +x SCRIPTNAME`)
Then execute it with the mentioned parameter for all your plists

This solution is not so convenient as the `agvtools` solution, but it should not stop your build when used in a dependency ...

Comment: Instead of using this as a build phase, you could put it in the hooks directory of your git/svn repo.

Comment: if you have that level of access, that might work - but I don't

Comment: Hi @dogsgod, I use svn and in my main app I use script which get the version number from svn. I see in ur example that used for git, is there away just to use in my extension that can inherit directly from main app plist, the version .

Answer (score 6):

I have a Run Script that I attach to my main app target. It will propagate the WatchKit Extension and the WatchKit app upon building the app.

It is completely reusable. Enjoy!

```
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")

buildNumberDec=$(($buildNumber + 1))

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumberDec" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumberDec" "$SRCROOT/${PRODUCT_NAME} WatchKit Extension/Info.plist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumberDec" "$SRCROOT/${PRODUCT_NAME} WatchKit App/Info.plist"
```

Comment: This is nearly an exact duplicate of Lucien.

Comment: Is anything original anymore?!? :) It's just pulling the Product Name to allow for a more re-usable experience.

Comment: It's not only a duplicate of other answers, it's also highly redundant and does not add anything new

Comment: I had to add this run script just after the **Copy Bundle Resources**, otherwise I got a failed build with complaining on non matching version numbers (however after the build the version numbers where all identical).

Answer (score 6):

## Simple, Easy, No Scripting Needed

### Tested with Xcode 13.4.1

This is by far the easiest way to sync build numbers and marketing versions across your targets.

### Step 1

Make sure that the project's `Current Project Version` and `Marketing Version` are set. This will be the single source of truth for your build number and marketing version. Find these settings by clicking the project in the navigator, clicking the project (above the targets), and typing "versioning" into the filter.

[image: Set project build number and marketing version]

### Step 2

#### Sync Build Number / Project Version (e.g. 123)

In your targets, go to the `Build Settings` tab and set `Current Project Version` to `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)`.

In your .plist files set `Bundle version` (same as `CFBundleVersion`) to `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)`.

#### Sync Marketing Version (e.g. 1.2.3)

In your targets, go to the `Build Settings` tab and set `Marketing Version` to `$(MARKETING_VERSION)`

In your .plist files set `Bundle version string (short)` (same as `CFBundleShortVersionString`) to `$(MARKETING_VERSION)`.

[Here's a link to my blog post on the topic with more helpful screenshots](https://www.theswift.dev/posts/easily-keep-build-numbers-and-marketing-versions-in-sync).

Comment: This solution works. Do you have any suggestion how to increase the build number in the project file correctly?

Answer (score 3):

If it would be useful to supplement other answers with my own personal experience. These centred around build failure caused by `ValidateEmbeddedBinary`.

`ValidateEmbeddedBinary` will fail if the `CFBundleVersion` is not the same in the embedded WatchKit app and the parent app.

The error looks something like:

> (null): error: The value of CFBundleVersion in your WatchKit app's
>   Info.plist (1234) does not match the value in your companion app's
>   Info.plist (7931). These values are required to match.

Working in XCode 7.3, the following will first update the parent app's plist. Then it updates the Debug or Release WatchKit app before `PBXCp` executes to copy it to the parent app directory:

```
#!/bin/sh

git=`sh /etc/profile; which git`
appBuild=`"$git" rev-list HEAD --count`

appPlistPath="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_PATH}"
watchKitPlistPath="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/../${CONFIGURATION}-watchos/${PRODUCT_NAME} WatchKit App.app/Info.plist"

echo "Setting App CFBundleVersion $appBuild at info plist path at ${appPlistPath}"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $appBuild" "${appPlistPath}"

echo "Setting WatchKit App CFBundleVersion $appBuild at ${watchKitPlistPath}"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $appBuild" "${watchKitPlistPath}"
```

The above uses git's commit count as `CFBundleVersion`.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's helpful to know how to define the `watchKitPlistPath` within `${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}`, since that is not tracked by Git.

Answer (score 1):

To extend this thread, if someone encounters similar problem as me, hopefully script below will help.

For instance, I have `watch target`, `watch extension`, and an `app share extension` in my project.

I used run phase to update project's plist as suggested, and it works if I build the project, the .plist files are all updated as expected.

However the problem is when you archiving app(let's say all targets have different build number), the info plist in the archived projects was not updated.
After a few times of try out, I found extension's plist files were copied before this run phase, and then the run phase script(updating project's plist) won't help with the archived plist.
So I eventually changed the script to update compiled target's plist, and it works as I expected, I have same build number for all the targets in the application.
Here is how I did it:
add this script to each target's build phase:

```
infoPlistPath="${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH}/Info.plist"
PLISTBUDDY="/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy"
buildNumber=$(git rev-list HEAD | wc -l | tr -d ' ')
$PLISTBUDDY -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "${infoPlistPath}"
```

For different target, this `EXECUTABLE_FOLDER_PATH` was different, and it will update the compiled target's info plist, instead of the project's info plist.
Just a note I checked "Run script only when installing" as well since I only need this to be run for archiving

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply add the same Build Phase to **EACH** of your targets.

```
#Update build number with number of git commits if in release mode
if [ ${CONFIGURATION} == "Release" ]; then
buildNumber=$(git rev-list HEAD | wc -l | tr -d ' ')
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
fi;
```

So if you have a Watch App, a Watch App Extension, a Widget Extension, or whatever else extension, go to each of their Build Phases, add a *New Run Script Phase* and paste the above.