# Analogue of git tag hook

Tags: git, githooks, tagging, git-tag

Do you have any ideas how can I fire a script while I'm making tagging?

I know that currently there is no a separate git tag hook but it should be some way how to do that. For instance, try to use `pre-push` hook while you push your tags or something similar. Did anyone do such things?

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no hook, you would need to make an alias, or your own `git-tag` script, in order to wrap the [`git tag`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) command.

That way, you can tag *and* execute other commands.

As mentioned in [your next question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38736656/6309), you could use a `pre-push` hook to make that analysis, but by then, there could be a bit late (many commits could have been created, and many tags set before the user finally pushes)

Comment: It is a good trick but how can I inject this solution to a group of developers in production?

Comment: @AndreyRozumnyi By sharing that script `git-tag` on a shared PATH folder, folder they must declare in their PATH *before* the git.exe folder.

Comment: and can I reject the tagging if some conditions in the project don't hold? For instances, some of the references in git external file are untagged?

Comment: @AndreyRozumnyi Yes, either in your script, or centrally in a pre-receive hook.

Comment: how can I do that in pre-receive hook, as in the provided example I need an access to the client project file. Git tag object by itself contains only metadata, so I don't see an option to do that centrally in this case or I missed something?

Comment: @AndreyRozumnyi in that case, you need to check at the client-side script level indeed.

Comment: Possible to provide a sample alias which grabs current version and increments it?

Comment: @jbord39 on the client side, it really depends on the nature of your project. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/q/6286937/6309