# Can I use git pre-push hook only for that case when I made a new tag?

Tags: git, githooks, git-tag

I would like to use git pre-push hook only for that cases when I added a new tag. Can I somehow analyze the push for this information?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the Git [githooks](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push) documentation for **pre-push**:

> Information about what is to be pushed is provided on the hook’s standard input with lines of the form:
>
> ```
> <local ref> SP <local sha1> SP <remote ref> SP <remote sha1> LF
> ```
>
> For instance, if the command git push origin master:foreign were run the hook would receive a line like the following:
>
> ```
> refs/heads/master 67890 refs/heads/foreign 12345
> ```

So when a **tag** is pushed there should be a line starting with `refs/tags/`.

Check for this and execute your hook conditionally.